# Doctrine queryBuilder setParamater

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem using Parameters in the Doctrine queryBuilder.

Here's my code:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'value')
    ->from('test')
    ->where('id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', '1', 'integer')
;
```

This creates:

```
SELECT id, value FROM test WHERE id = :id
```

However the setParameter is not applied when I use

```
$stmt = $conn->query($queryBuilder);
```

Getting this Error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id'..."

What am I missing?

Using this works, but I would prefer to integrate the parameters directly in the queryBuilder:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($queryBuilder);
$stmt->bindValue("id", "1", "integer");
$stmt->execute();
```

Any hints would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to directly execute the querybuilder, this will attach the paramaters correctly.

Example:

```
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'value')
    ->from('test')
    ->where('id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', '1', 'integer');

$queryBuilder->execute();
```